# Window glass in 2002 Jeep Liberty is stuck in regulator even after clips removed

Tags: jeep, replace, power-windows

I am attempting to remove the window glass from my driver-side front door so I can replace the window regulator. I have removed the two metal clips that hold the glass in the lift plate. Now the window is loose in the lift plate, but I can't pull the glass out of it - it is still holding on somehow. Is there anything else I should have disconnected?

My regulator is stuck at the bottom position, so I have very little leverage to pull the window up (I had to loosen the bolts and raise the regulator an inch or so just to reach the clips).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it worked out. I hadn't realized there were pins sticking out of the bottom of the window into the lift plate - window had to be moved laterally (and pretty forcefully), not just up. A mechanic in my area took 5 minutes to come out and help me in his parking lot and figured it out. Props to Auto Doctor in Crofton, MD, for anyone in this area.

I believe the white plastic ovals on this photo are where the pins connected:
[image]

Comment: if you took any sharing some photos could go a long way to help folks down the road.

Comment: Unfortunately I sold this vehicle shortly after repairing the window (10+ years ago now) and no longer have any photos of the regulator.

As I recall, where the lift plate holds the bottom of the window, there were two small (around 1 inch long) metal pins attached to the glass, which poked through holes/grommets on the lift plate and held the glass securely even if two metal clips are removed. The glass/lift plate had to be raised a few inches so that those parts could be moved apart sideways (eg towards and away from you as you're looking at the part with the door inner panel off).

Comment: @jxramos I've added a stock photo that shows what I'm talking about (I think)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any sort of loosing oil, like WD40? The glass might simply be stuck to the rubber seals that keep it from cracking in the clamps. If you can't see any other clamps, and it is still stuck; spray some WD40(or whatever) in there and gently separate the glass from rubber. I had this problem happen a couple of times on older BMWs while replacing regulators.